# jQuery doesn't addClass to HTML element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When try to `addClass('hidden')` to `$(this)` it seems to add it to jQuery object `[textarea.form-control.hidden, prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: button.btn.btn-info.btn-flat.hidden, selector: "textarea"]`, but not to actual HTML element. What am I missing?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/34sdrrnf/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have already function called on main div '.item' so when you click on button the above function on '.item' calls again as button is child of `.item`.

Use `e.stopPropagation();` to stop calling function from parent div.

```
$('.item button').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    $parent.find('span').removeClass('hidden');
    $parent.find('textarea').addClass('hidden');
    $parent.find('button').addClass('hidden');

    console.log($parent.find('textarea'));
  })
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/34sdrrnf/1/